# importing PyQt4 modules gives Segmentation Fault after PyQt5 install

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, pyqt4

I'm using python 3.5.2 (64 bit) within a operating system Linux Mint 18 with a kernel release 4.4.0-109-generic.

A long time ago I installed PyQt4 through `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4` and everything worked perfectly, untill I recently installed through pip `PyQt5`.

Since then, I'm able to `import PyQt4` and `import PyQt4.pyqtconfig` but not the modules like `import PyQt4.QtCore`, `import PyQt4.QtGui` or `import PyQt4.Qt` for which exits python with 'Segmentation Fault'. I've also realized that the command (within python enviroment) `help('modules')` gives same output after some seconds.

I've tried to remove PyQt5 with pip and reinstall PyQt4 from terminal (version 4.11.4+dfsg-1build4), but nothing seems to change. I also can see the directory from the PyQt4 from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4`

I've also tried to create a python virtual environment with `virtualenv env --python=python3.5` inside a folder and copy the whole directory from PyQt4 to the dist-packages of the environment and also install `sip` within it. Using `sip` 4.19.8 version from pip.

Another thing I've tried is to use `gdb python3` to run a python program that only contains the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import PyQt4.QtCore
```

What it returns is this:

```
$ gdb -q python3
Reading symbols from python3...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/59/a8ef36ca241df24686952480966d7bc0d7c6ea.debug...done.
done.
(gdb) run FaultPy35.py 
Starting program: /usr/bin/python3 FaultPy35.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
PyType_IsSubtype () at ../Objects/typeobject.c:1343
1343    ../Objects/typeobject.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb)
```

I'm really new to gdb but apparently the problem goes beyond python packages...

Note: I've checked via `dpkg-query -L python3-pyqt4` what the package `python3-pyqt4` has installed in the following list:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python3-pyqt4
/usr/share/doc/python3-pyqt4/THANKS
/usr/share/doc/python3-pyqt4/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python3-pyqt4/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtHelp.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/qtproxies.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/proxy_metaclass.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/compiler.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/indenter.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/misc.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/qobjectcreator.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/objcreator.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Loader
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Loader/loader.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Loader/qobjectcreator.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Loader/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/driver.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/properties.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/uiparser.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/port_v3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/port_v3/invoke.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/port_v3/ascii_upper.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/port_v3/proxy_base.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/port_v3/load_plugin.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/port_v3/as_string.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/port_v3/string_io.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/port_v3/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/phonon.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/qtwebkit.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/qtdeclarative.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/qaxcontainer.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/qscintilla.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/icon_cache.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/exceptions.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtSvg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/Qt.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/pyqtconfig.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtScriptTools.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/pyqtconfig_nd5.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtDesigner.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtDeclarative.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtNetwork.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtXml.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtWebKit.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtDBus.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtAssistant.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtXmlPatterns.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtTest.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtScript.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Any Ideas?

**Update (25/04/18)**

I tried the python 3.5 debug build at import time:

```
$ python3-dbg
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt4
>>> import PyQt4.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtCore'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtCore'
>>>
```